# Haskell: Using patten matching with currying data

Tags: haskell, currying

Is it possible to use patten matching with a currying data? Suppose the following code:

```
data Bind = Echo String | Sum Int Int

getOperation (Echo  x )  =  "Echo"
getOperation (Sum  x y ) = "Sum"

main = getOperation (Sum 1)
```

It fails because `Sum 1` has type `Int -> Bind`, and `getOperation` has type `Bind -> String` .

My itention is to get a string that itentifies the used data constructor  even if the data is curried. Something like this fake code:

```
getOperation (Echo  x )  =  "Echo"
getOperation (Echo) = "Echo"       -- Pattern matching for curried data
getOperation (Sum  x y ) = "Sum"
getOperation (Sum x) = "Sum"       -- Pattern matching for curried data
```

Comment: as you said yourself `Echo` is `String -> Bind` - so right now it's a function taking a `String` and returning a `Bind` and sadly you cannot pattern-match functions (it could be `\ _ -> Sum 0 0` as well for all `getOperation` knows at this point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching a name to a value is no problem.

```
data Named a = Named { name :: String, value :: a }

-- there is a very natural Functor instance for Named as well, which
-- could be used to implement this
(<$$>) :: Named (a -> b) -> a -> Named b
Named n f <$$> x = Named n (f x)
```

Here's a sample of how to use it:

```
data Bind = Echo String | Add Int Int

echo :: Named (String -> Bind)
add  :: Named (Int -> Int -> Bind)
add  = Named "Add" Add
echo = Named "Echo" Echo

main = do
    putStrLn . name $ echo
    putStrLn . name $ echo <$$> "hi"
    putStrLn . name $ add
    putStrLn . name $ add <$$> 3
    putStrLn . name $ add <$$> 3 <$$> 4
```

This produces:

```
Echo
Echo
Add
Add
Add
```